# Path resolution in Web application when AngularJs is accessing and MVC4 server

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a modular applications by mixing the ASP.Net MVC4 and AngularJS. what MVC does is that it allows us to have a path separation like below.

Home screen
      `http://127.0.0.1:81/`

when a user logs in, i provide them with a base path as below

```
  `http://127.0.0.1:81/shipper/#/operations/home`
```

or

```
  `http://127.0.0.1:81/client/#/orders/home`
```

so I get a base screen template per type of user and from then on it is a SPA that takes over on the template which sometimes share a common view based om the need.

**now the issue** i am having is that when i have to reference any server object like image on the web server that are all located in the `root\themes\images\image1.jpg`

the image URI in the fiddler is getting resolved to `http://127.0.0.1:81/client/themes/images/image1.jpg`

instead of

`http://127.0.0.1:81/themes/images/image1.jpg`

which obviously means this will fail.

my HTML looks like below:

`<img class="media-object" src="themes/images/img180x120.png" />`

is there a way I can override this to force it to ignore the /shipper or /client from the path ?

Regards, Kiran

Comment: Try <img class="media-object" src="/themes/images/img180x120.png" /> see if it works?

Comment: @chandermani : Thanks! didn't expect it to be such a simple solution :)

Comment: It is always good to try out some combination before asking, saves your time :) I will add it as an answer for reference.

Comment: @chandermani:  well I tried many combination ranging from from '../' to '~/' and what not, but missed to try out the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i turns out just preceeding the url with a `/` will make it a path relative the the host server.